# How to pass command line arguments from C program to the bash script?

Tags: shell, command-line, c

I have written one bash script and now I am calling this script from C program. Now I want to pass arguments i.e. `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to the script from command line.

Comment: You need to show some code. It depends on what you're using to invoke the script from the C program, but most likely it's something in the `exec*()` family of system calls. Those support passing command line arguments in quite a straightforward fashion. In fact you **must** pass command line arguments when using those system calls. Therefore I don't know where you're hitting some difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the way the script is called. For example, if you are using `system` you can preformat string that used to invoke bash script from system call adding command line arguments:

C

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        char command[100] = {0};

        sprintf(command, "./example.sh %s", argv[1]);
        system(command);
    }
}
```

Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
```

As a result

```
$ gcc example.c -o example && ./example Hello!
Hello!
```

Comment: Using `system()` is insecure. What if `argv[1]` contains a space or a shell metacharacter?

Comment: It is just an example. It is up to author to implement additional security and reliability checks.

Comment: I don't agree. I believe it is up to us experts to recommend secure interfaces like `fork()`+`execve()` instead of `system()`. If we recommend `system()`, people are going to use it and write insecure code.

Comment: @Calada, can you answer whit a secure solution?