# How to pass arguments to bash script from a cpp program

Tags: c++, bash, fork, exec, command-line-arguments

I've forked a child process which then calls a bash script using `execv`, the way i'm passing command line arguments to the script, It does not print first argument on doing `echo $1` inside the script.

```
std::string s = std::to_string(c_no);    
char *args[] = {(char *)s.c_str(), NULL};

pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
    execv("./ckpnt.sh", &args[0]);
}
```

consider `c_no` to be any integer.

What is the correct way to do this?

I've already refrenced this link [How to pass command line arguments from C program to the bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231318/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-from-c-program-to-the-bash-script) but this answer uses `system` system call and i try to not use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument passed to a program is its name so currently your number ends up in `$0`. `args` should be:

```
char *args[] = {"./ckpnt.sh", (char *)s.c_str(), NULL};
```

Comment: Still it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Works locally. Can you run the program under `strace -Ff` and see if it is passing arguments correctly?

Comment: I just checked `echo "$0"` is printing `./ckpnt.sh`  but `echo "$1"` is not printing anything

Comment: Make sure you're properly recompiling, and again, check with `strace -Ff` to see what is being passed.

Comment: the way i've passed arguments in `exec` line is correct ?

Comment: It has printed so many logs i cannot trace. does `F` option was very useful?

Comment: @ram Are you waiting on the child after you fork? The string might have been destroyed before `execv`

Comment: Look for the line that contains execve. For me, the second looks like `execve("./ckpnt.sh", ["./ckpnt.sh", "42"], 0x7ffe1b287738 /* 25 vars */) = 0`

Comment: @Artyer yes i'm waiting

Comment: @Botje this is some part of it :

Comment: `strace: deprecated option -F ignored
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffcbc4bc2d8 /* 17 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55eac7b8a000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffcfd4dc5e0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=116217, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 116217, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4ff3a6f000
close(3)                                = 0`

Comment: Actually, just use `strace -fe execve` to trace just the execve call.

Comment: yes, these are the lines: `execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x7ffe6416ae10 /* 17 vars */) = 0
strace: Process 23891 attached
[pid 23891] execve("./ckpnt.sh", ["1"], 0x7ffc1f671698 /* 17 vars */) = 0`

Comment: See the difference? You're only passing one argument to execve, I am passing two. Are you *sure* your code is according to my answer? And that you're running that newly compiled code?

Comment: Ok i'll try this too, but in the above code, i've passed `&arg[0]` to the `exec` and after your answer i just changed it to `&arg[1]`

Comment: That means you're back to the original behavior: passing one argument. You need to pass *two* arguments to execve in order for one to show up in $1.

Comment: @Botje Thanks, now it's printing 1 but i still don't understand why it was giving wrong answer earlier.